# Conserved quantities for Schrodinger equation?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Let $\Omega$ be an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$.  Consider the n-dimensional Hilbert space, $\mathbb{C}^n$, with the dynamics $|\dot{\psi}\rangle+i\Omega|\psi\rangle=0$. This may viewed as a finite-dimensional quantum system, with Hamiltonian $\Omega$.

For any $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, one can derived the  following fact:

\begin{equation}
\sum_jm_j\omega_j=0\Longrightarrow\frac{d}{dt}\left(\prod_j\langle\omega_j|\psi\rangle^{m_j}\right)=0
\end{equation}

So, $\Pi_j\langle\omega_j|\psi\rangle^{m_j}$ is a conserved quantity.  I think there may even be a true statement along the lines of: two trajectories can be distinguished by a conserved quantity if and only if they have different energy probability distributions, or they have different values for the above quantity using some $\bar{m}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Since these dynamics are like those that appear in quantum mechanics, it made me wonder if this conserved quantity has a name, and if conserved quantities of this form exist for the Schrodinger equation on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Do the coefficients $m_j$ really have to be integers for the derivation to work? This seems like a peculiar restriction.

Comment: You are probably right that there is a way to do this more generally, but restricting to integers prevents having to deal with the subtleties of complex exponentiation.  The main reason I restricted to integers, is because that is the case I was interested in originally, and because I think that integers are in a sense "sufficient" to get all of the conserved quantities you would want.

Comment: Why is it obvious that there even are nontrivial integer energy combinations that sum to zero? That is my concern here, being able to verify the hypothesis.

Comment: Also on the right side do you mean to have $\omega_j$ there? I think you want the eigenvectors...

Comment: Non-trivial integer combinations don't always exist, but they definitely do in some cases.  For example, if we use [[0,1+i],[1-i,0]] for the Hamiltonian.  So, yeah, you only get interesting conserved quantities of this form when you have such combinations.

Comment: Powers of amplitudes higher than 2 are rare in quantum mechanics, and go against the grain and philosophy of the Hilbert space formulation.

Comment: Since the probabilities of each energy (i.e. $|\langle w_j|\psi\rangle|^2$) are conserved, one can factor out $\Pi_j |\langle w_j|\psi\rangle|^{m_j}$ from the conserved quantity.  What is left behind is a conserved quantity that only says something about the relative phases of  the components of $\psi$.  Specifically, that $\Sigma_j \theta_jm_j$ is constant modulo $2\pi$ (where $\theta_j$ is the phase of the $j^{th}$ component of $\psi$, or any other angle that differs by a multiple of $2\pi$).  Is that description more aligned with the philosophy of the Hilbert space formulation?